# Where to put the qt5 resource files after building an executable?

Tags: visual-studio, qt

I developed a Qt5 application for Windows on Visual Studio. I installed Qt Visual Studio addin, and add resource files using Qt resource editor. It works when I execute my program by clicking `Start Debugging` button. However, when I try to start the program by clicking the `.exe` file, all the icons are missing. Where should I put the resource files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resource files are embedded in your executable. The reason for icons not showing up is something different, probably related to missing plugins (e.g. if you use .svg files you will need to deploy the respective qsvg plugins from {QTDIR}/plugins/iconengines or {QTDIR}/plugins/imageformats).

The reason why this is working when starting from Visual Studio is that it automatically adds your Qt directory to the path.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I used .svg files. All the .svg icons are missing, but .png ones are fine. Problem solved. Thanks!.